# After update Bibtex causes error: "I found no \citation commands"

Tags: bibtex, ubuntu

I'm not sure what is going on - i think the error started after updating ubuntu to 19.10. I have this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This causes an error on builds:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: AAmain.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file AAmain.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file AAmain.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file AAmain.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

My search on this error suggested that Biber instead of Bibtex is running, but I cant see how Biber suddenly should be activated.
Would love your input on this. I'm ausing pdflatex as a compiler.

Comment: Erh that is normal, bibtex is telling you that there is no information in this document that it can work with. And there is no data in your MWE related to bibliographies. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That's expected. BibTeX didn't find any citation (`\citation` commands), any bibliography database (`\bibdata` command) nor a bibliography style (`\bibstyle` command). As soon as you add at least one citation (with `\cite` or some other command), one bibliography database (a `.bib` file, with `\bibliography{file}`), and a bibliography style (with `\bibliographystyle`), then the errors will go away.

Comment: @daleif My issue is no pdf is being build - my editor throws this error and nothing happens. It's a new error that i haven't seen before updating

Comment: Thank you @PhelypeOleinik! Do you think my editor is calling bibtex somehow? I'm not sure why bibtex wwants to scan the document i know there is no citations, i haven't even called bibtex in the document

Comment: @PernkDernets Yes, definitely it is. That error is BibTeX's. What editor are you using?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm using Atom, with the "Atom latex" package. My compiler is pdflatex, on Unbuntu 19.10

Comment: @PernkDernets I've never used Atom, but it seems to be a common problem. This link seems promising: https://github.com/ashthespy/Atom-LaTeX/issues/14#issuecomment-370271727

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Great find! Thank you very much! It solved my issue right away. Please post it as a answer so i can endorse/praise you.

Comment: @PernkDernets I don't know about Atom so the best I could do would be to post the link (which would make a really bad answer). Please post yourself the answer with how you did to solve the problem. Others might run into this problem in the future.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik good idea

Answer (score 2):

Talking with [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) in the comment section, it was suggested my editor called Bibtex on its own. The editor I use is Atom, with the package "Atom Latex". The issue has been discussed on the [package on github](https://github.com/ashthespy/Atom-LaTeX/issues/14#issuecomment-370271727).

Adding the following to the "Custom toolchain commands" in the package settings solved my issue. (Bibtex still works when you actually call it):

```
%TEX %ARG %DOC && %TEX %ARG %DOC
```